# How to use Intel C++ Compiler with NetBeans (Windows)

Tags: c++, netbeans, intel, icc

In order to use ICC with NetBeans, a new [toolchain](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/toolchain.html) has to be created.

Does anyone has already created a [toolchain](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/toolchain.html) for ICC and NetBeans ?
If not, is there another way to use ICC with NetBeans ?

Answer (score 0):

[VCC4N](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42519/vcc4n-visual-c-compiler-for-netbeans) is a Netbeans plugin for supporting Visual C++. Since Intel's compiler is pretty similar to VC++ (similar command-line options, debugger compatibility, etc.), it is likely this plugin can be modified to support ICC. I know, it's not a real solution (I haven't found one), but it could be a start.